# Removing The IMG SRC tag in Wordpress

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to remove the "img src" tag from the php so it'll simply display the images url, rather than displaying the actual image. This is the code I've got so far and it works perfectly, but when it's rendered it shows thumbnails instead of urls.

```
<?php $pics = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pics', true ); 
    foreach( $pics as $pics) 
    {
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $pics['pictures'] );
        echo '<img src="' . $image_attributes[0] . '" />';
    }
?>
```

I know theres a way to do this, but I don't know how to remove the tags without breaking the image code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you do `var_dump($image_attributes);` and show us the output?

Comment: why dont you simple use echo $image_attributes[0];

Comment: $image_attributes[0] worked, thanks Ash. I know it seems kind of noob, but Im just learning PHP lol. Thanks alot everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to `echo` the image src and not display it as an image then change

```
echo '<img src="' . $image_attributes[0] . '" />';
```

to

```
 echo $image_attributes[0];
```

---

```
<?php 

    $pics = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pics', true ); 
    foreach( $pics as $pics) 
    {
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $pics['pictures'] );
        echo $image_attributes[0];
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So do you want to show on the page the "html code" with the tag and the src attribute?

Have you tried to enclose "img" tag within "pre" tag?

```
echo '<pre><img src="' . $image_attributes[0] . '" /></pre>';
```